# Is it ok to call Published properties from an ObservableObject class in other classes in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

a Service class where I process all Core Data transactions for a single entity/Object and I often find my self needing to access information from other classes and I was wondering if there was an issue by calling these classes in non-UI related classes.

In the following code I'm calling the `dogs` array from the `DogService` class inside the `DogHouseService` class, and I was wondering if this could be an issue.

Are there any possible issue by calling `@Published` properties from an `ObservableObject` class inside other classes?

#### ObservableObject class

```
 class DogService: ObservableObject{

    let manager: CoreDataManager

    @Published var dogs: [Dog] = []

    init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
      self.manager = coreDataManager
      loadDogs()
    }

    //Adds, Deletes, Updates, etc.

    func loadDogs(){
      let request = NSFetchRequest<Dog>(entityName: "Dog")
      do{
        dogs =  try manager.context.fetch(request)
      }catch let error{
        print("Error fetching dogs. \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }

    func save(){
      self.manager.save()
    }
  }
```

#### Other Class

```
  class DogHouseService{
    let dogService = DogService()

    for dog in dogService.dogs{
      // do something
    }
  }
```

#### Core Data Manager

```
    class CoreDataManager{
        // Singleton
        static let instance = CoreDataManager()
    
        @AppStorage(UserDefaults.Keys.iCloudSyncKey) private var iCloudSync = false
            
        /// This property is strictly to be used in the Preview struct in Canvas.
        static var preview: CoreDataManager = {
            let result = CoreDataManager(inMemory: true)
            let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
            // create preview objects here
    
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
              
            }
            return result
        }()
        
        lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
           return container.viewContext
        }()
        
        lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
           return setupContainer()
        }()
        
        init(inMemory: Bool = false){
            /// for preview purposes only, remove if no previews are needed.
            if inMemory {
                container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
            }
        }
        
        func setupContainer()->NSPersistentContainer{
            let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataContainer")
            
            guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else{
                fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
            }
            
            description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
            // Generate notifications on remote changes
            description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
            
            if iCloudSync{
                // turn iCloud sync OnThank
                let cloudKitContainerIdentifier = "iCloud.com.domain.MyAppName"
                let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: cloudKitContainerIdentifier)
                description.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
            }else{
                // turn iCloud sync Off
                description.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
            }
            
            container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
                }
            }
            container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    
            return container
        }
        
        func save(){
            do{
                try context.save()
            }catch let error{
                print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 04/10/2020: Added Core Data Manager code.

Comment: Nope, that's fine.

Comment: It's even the usual/recommended way.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't sure since I was under the impression that the `@Published` wrapper was mainly designed to be used to update the UI.

Comment: To make it clear: Updating `dogs` in `DogService` does not re-run the repeat loop in  `DogHouseService`, but it's no problem at all to access published properties from other classes.

Comment: Got it, I wasn't really expecting that but thank you for clarifying that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Normally your UI code uses a view context and your non-UI code uses background contexts. You can write your entity logic in a `NSManagedObject` subclass or in a `NSManagedObject` extension. That way you can make use of the same logic in different contexts. The context is like a service already, you don't need another object for it.

Comment: @ malhal - Would you mind elaborating a little more on the code structure you proposed, I'm really interested since it may answer other questions I had about managing Core Data in general. I just posted the code for my Core Data Manager class for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/loading_and_displaying_a_large_data_feed